# How to use a Stylus variable in calc?

Tags: css, stylus, css-calc

In Stylus, how do I use a [variable](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/variables.html) in a [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) expression?

For example, the following doesn't work (`arrow-size` being a variable):

```
arrow-size = 5px
left calc(50% - arrow-size)
```

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, Stylus lets you do the calculation directly: `left (50% - arrow-size)`. But I guess there might be times when you want the actual `calc` to show up

Comment: `left (50% - arrow-size)` becomes `45%`, which isn't correct if you're mixing units like that.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In order to use a Stylus variable inside a calc expression, one must employ the [string % operator](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/operators.html#sprintf):

```
arrow-size = 5px
left "calc(50% - %s)" % arrow-size
```

Answer (score 60):

To use **multiple variables** (not just one) in calc (or with other functions), i use [**sprintf**](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/operators.html#sprintf) as you used, but with tuples:

```
arrow-size = 5px
measure = 50%
left "calc(%s - %s)" % (measure arrow-size)
```

Remember that [**interpolation**](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html) in Stylus is supported through `{}` and it's used for other kind of interpolation. It's used to surround an expression, which then becomes part of a identifier, or a selector.