# stylus + CSS function bug

Tags: css, function, sass, stylus, calc

I'm having trouble using variables and functions with STYLUS

Check out my [demo](https://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/GmoKmx?editors=0100)

**Using no variable works fine:**

```
.div
  position relative
  background #3cd
  width calc(100vw - 10em)
  height calc(100vh - 10em)
  margin 5em
```

**Using variables breaks:**

```
$var = 10em

.div
  position relative
  background #3cd
  width calc(100vw - $var)
  height calc(100vh - $var)
  margin calc($var / 2)
```

Any ideas? I also tried string % operators, no luck. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a Stylus variable in calc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272158/how-to-use-a-stylus-variable-in-calc)

Answer (score 0):

hh, I think you should check out the stylus syntax.
When you use stylus variables, "calc()" should not be added.
Try directly for example `margin $var / 2` instead of `margin calc($var / 2)`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried removing the calc() functions, however it's still broken https://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/RVrbJy?editors=0100

Comment: I think it results from your `body` and its css property. I rewrite your code as follows: `<body><div class="div"></div></body>` and css `body{height: 600px}`. It works.

Comment: And there is another bug I ignored before, you should add brackets for `$var / 2`, that is `($var / 2)`

Comment: I made those changes in the demo but it doesn't work, is it working for you when you edit my pen?

Comment: @kathrynm yeah, I edited in your pen and it worked. Do you add brackets for `margin` property? i.e. `margin ($var / 2)`

Comment: could you share your pen with me please?

Comment: @kathrynm I think I have got your problem. Here is the demo I meet with problems: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWroZw?editors=1100#anon-signup. It seems that stylus can't handle `vw - em`. According to the stylus documentation:     >Multiplicative and additive binary operators work as expected. Type conversion is applied within unit type classes, or default to the literal value. For example 5s - 2px results in 3s.    So when you check the compiled css, you will get `width: 90vw`.