# How to add a CSS var() into a stylus built-in function?

Tags: css, stylus

I tried this:

```
:root {
  --primary-color: $black
}

$secondary-color = "lighten(%s, 20%)" % var(--primary-color)
```

(I took it from here: [How to use a Stylus variable in calc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272158/how-to-use-a-stylus-variable-in-calc))

I don't receive any errors. However, `$secondary-color` doesn't render any color.

What's the best way of doing this?

The result is this:

`background-color: lighten(var(--primary-color), 20%)` so I think something is not rendering well.

Comment: I think you missed a `;` after `$black` which is why Stylus misinterprets it.
And black is not a good variable name as it is also a html color code (shouldn't matter because of the `$`). Is it defined before or did you want simply `black`?

Comment: @alex I have the same problem where I cannot write `alpha(var(--primary), .6)` it bugs for me when I do this. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work because 1. `lighten` is a pre-processor function that's executed at compile-time while interpolation is just passing through all the stuff and 2. `lighten` isn't supposed to work with css variables at all because it's extracting numerical values from a color in order to compute another color at compile-time which in case of a css variable just isn't known at that time and furthermore 3. in css this isn't even possible with a css variable containing a full color definition and so a pre-processor couldn't do either: in order to make color mixing work at run-time you would need to break it up like `var(--primary-h)`, `var(--primary-s)` and `var-primary-l` and use `calc` to operate on the values separately.